# Symfony2 - maxSize parameter not working on file upload

Tags: php, validation, symfony, file-upload

I have a file uploading function on my Symfony2 project.

I am seting the maxSize parameter like that:

```
$manuscript_file = new File(array(
        'maxSize' => '20M',
        'mimeTypes' => array(
            'application/msword',
            'application/zip',
        ),
        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid manuscript file. Valid types are: doc, docx, zip',
    ));
```

The problem is that when I am trying to upload a 2M or 3M word file, I am getting the validation message:

```
 The file is too large. Allowed maximum size is 20M bytes.
```

Did you faced that? Or is my code wrong.

I took the example from the Symfony documentation:

[Symfony File - Validation Constraints Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/constraints/File.html#maxsize)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I already faces this issue, so I post this solution (I think this is the same issue for you).

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5551) of Symfony, in fact the framework will display the validator error message also when the file size is too high for your PHP configuration, instead of getting the classical PHP error.

In your current PHP config, you probably limited the max upload size to 2M, so Symfony display the wrong error.

So check your **php.ini** file (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini on Linux) and increase max_upload_size to fit your field :

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

Don't forget to restart apache : `apache2ctl restart`

Now it should work !

Note that's probably fixed on the last Symfony version, another solution is perhaps to upgrade your project to sf2.3 (but i'm not sure of that) ^^

Comment: Perfect, it works now, I changed the upload_max_filesize = 30M in the php.ini file. What do you think about this value, is this ok?

Comment: It depends totally of your machine storage capabilities and what you stores on your server. For word (or open) doc, I think it's totally correct, they are rarely higher !

Comment: Keep in mind that `post_max_size` parameter should also match the size of your max allowed file. Otherwise you would continue having same error as OP.  So you *MUST* add `post_max_size = 21M` to your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I created a jQuery validation method to prevent sending big files to server because php don't valide it (It is in Spanish):

```
$(function() {
    //Validate 20MB
    validarFileSize('#carga_telefonos_form_file', {{ 10*1024*1024 }}, '#div-mensaje-file-size', '#botonSubmit');
});

function validarFileSize(campo, maximo, divMensaje, btnGuardar) {
    console.debug("validarFileSize. Campo: " + campo + ", maximo: " + maximo);
    $(campo).bind('change', function() {
        var size = this.files[0].size;
        if (size > maximo) {
            $(divMensaje).show();
            $(btnGuardar).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $(divMensaje).hide();
            $(btnGuardar).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using POST to upload your file, beware with **post_max_size** limit in php.ini